# Clamd process is slow to scan files of certain file extensions and sizes

Tags: alpine-linux, clamav

I've clamd process running on a Linux Docker container using https://hub.docker.com/r/mkodockx/docker-clamav/

My use case is my service will scan any attachments that a user uploads and return the scan status as response to the uploading service.

I've noticed that it takes a very long time(~2 mins) to scan certain files for example .pdf files of even smaller sizes like 12 MB.

```
bash-5.0$ clamdscan 12MB-PDF.pdf
/tmp/12MB-PDF.pdf: OK
 
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Time: 121.192 sec (2 m 1 s)
Start Date: 2021:08:24 16:02:09
End Date:   2021:08:24 16:04:10
bash-5.0$
 

bash-5.0$ top
Mem: 4102684K used, 4050300K free, 412640K shrd, 30660K buff, 2356148K cached
CPU:  16% usr   0% sys   0% nic  83% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 0.21 0.07 0.02 2/524 1844
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ CPU %CPU COMMAND
   26     1 clamav   S    1251m  15%   4  17% clamd
   25     1 clamav   S     9372   0%   3   0% freshclam -d
 1844   553 clamav   S     5884   0%   1   0% clamdscan 12MB-PDF.pdf
  553     0 clamav   S     2420   0%   5   0% bash
  560     0 clamav   S     2412   0%   3   0% bash
    1     0 clamav   S     2228   0%   1   0% {bootstrap.sh} /bin/bash /bootstrap.sh
  567   560 clamav   R     1584   0%   3   0% top
```

Below is my clamd.conf for reference.

```
###############
# General
###############

DatabaseDirectory /var/lib/clamav
TemporaryDirectory /tmp
LogTime yes
PidFile /run/clamav/clamd.pid
LocalSocket /run/clamav/clamd.sock
TCPSocket 3310
Foreground yes

###############
# Results
###############

DetectPUA yes
ExcludePUA NetTool
ExcludePUA PWTool
AlgorithmicDetection yes
Bytecode yes

###############
# Scan
###############

ScanPE yes
DisableCertCheck yes
ScanELF yes
AlertBrokenExecutables yes
ScanOLE2 yes
ScanPDF yes
ScanSWF yes
ScanMail yes
PhishingSignatures yes
PhishingScanURLs yes
ScanHTML yes
ScanArchive yes

###############
# Scan
###############

MaxScanSize 2000M
MaxFileSize 2000M
StreamMaxLength 2000M
MaxRecursion 30
MaxFiles 50000
MaxEmbeddedPE 40M
MaxHTMLNormalize 40M
MaxHTMLNoTags 2M
MaxScriptNormalize 5M
MaxZipTypeRcg 1M
MaxPartitions 128
MaxIconsPE 200
PCREMatchLimit 10000
PCRERecMatchLimit 10000
```

The same slow performance is noticed for a bigger .bin file of 1GB or so, where it takes more than 2 mins to scan the file and provide the scan result.

Please can someone provide any tips on how to optimise the scan times?

Thanks.

Comment: This is due to the fact that clamav is loading the database each time it's starting. Post an output of a scan where you think it's not slow

Comment: @Alex I thought it was just clamscan that loads the DB in memory each time. In my case, I have the clamd process running continuously and use clamdscan utility to test.

Comment: I think I found the root cause of the issue. I had MaxScanSize set to 2000M. On changing to the default 100M, 50MB PDF was scanned in 6 secs. So it looks like this setting isn't to be messed around with.

Comment: If you found the solution yourself, please consider writing it up as [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) for other users who may come here with the same problem.